# Atg dyn exception

Tags: atg, atg-dynamo

I face the below error while trying to run http://localhost:7103/dyn/admin/ 
atg 10.1.2 on windows 7 dyn/admin

```
The detailed exception is: java.io.IOException:
Cannot run program "javac": CreateProcess error=87, 
The parameter is incorrect
```

this appear because windows has limitation on command parameter lenght
please advice how to solve this issue.

Answer (score 2):

According to the ATG Support site:

> Oracle Commerce ATG will convert JHTML pages into Java servlets and
>   then compile them into class files using the javac Java compiler. By
>   default, the javac executable is invoked to perform the page
>   compilation.

These errors point to a low level problem invoking the javac compiler. `error=87` is mainly a problem on WebLogic 12 which has many different libraries in deeply nested directories.

The solution (which works for me on ATG11.1 and Weblogic 12.1.3) is

Edit or create the files

```
<ATG_Home>/localconfig/atg/dynamo/servlet/pagecompile/PageProcessor.properties
<ATG_Home>/localconfig/atg/dynamo/servlet/pagecompile/ExtendedJhtmlPageProcessor.properties
```

(I prefer to create them in an `<ATG_Data>/servers/<servername>/localconfig/...` folder but not sure of your setup)

Add these lines to the created above.

```
# Use java's internal compiler - only use this when using Oracle's JVM.
javaCompilerClassName=atg.servlet.pagecompile.SunJavaSourceCompiler
```